# What's the better what to add constrains in OptaPlanner

Tags: optaplanner

I am building an OptaPlan solution for an optimization problem.

I have an `List<Integer>` called weights
These are the only `planning variable` in my model, all others are shadow.

I want to make sure that sum of weights `(weights[0] + weights[1] + weights[2]... = 1000)` , While variables other than weights (`shadow`) will make sure whats the best solution (Using `SimpleScore`).

Using a simple `EasyScoreCalculator` might produce a huge set to search for my problem. I believe penalizing score every time for `weights[0] + weights[1] + weights[2]... != 1000` is an un-optimized (slow) method.

Whats the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should penalize the difference between that sum and 1000. So for example, if the weight sum in 920, penalize -80. If the weight it 1019, penalize -19.

Take a look at the cloud balancing problem, I suspect you'll need to just sum all the weights of the items that have @PlanningVariable Boolean included equal to true.